# How to extend WPF Path control

Tags: c#, wpf, path, shapes

In my windows form application which hosting a WPF composite control as an internal display of air condition system. In this diagram, each gas pipe and fluid pipe are represented by a Path control. We would like the color (using Path.Fill) of those Path object to represent the pressure alert state, such as low alert, medium alert, or high alert.

Part of the code we had is listed as:

```
<local:UC_Line_1 Margin="27.728,16.486,39.219,36.308" DataContext="{Binding Pipe1Alert}"/>
<local:UC_Line_2 Margin="21.172,15.322,33.218,6.876"  DataContext="{Binding Pipe2Alert}"/>
<local:UC_Line_3 Margin="46.907,0,31.36,26.178" DataContext="{Binding Pipe3Alert}"/>
<local:UC_Line_4 Margin="0,11.939,20.842,13.835" DataContext="{Binding Pipe4Alert}"/>
```

Each UC_Line_x control has the similar code like:

```
<UserControl
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:enum="clr-namespace:KPRC.App.AC.Enums"
x:Class="KPRC.App.AC.UC_Line_2"
x:Name="Line_2">
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <!-- Colors -->
    <!--Red Fill Color-->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="RedFill" Color="Red"/>
    <!--Yellow Fill Color-->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="YellowFill" Color="Yellow"/>
    <!--Orange Fill Color-->
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="OrangeFill" Color="Orange"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="UC_Line_2_LayoutRoot">
    <Path x:Name="FL_2" Stretch="Fill" Data="M20.167,0 L24.167,0 24.167,28.924 44,28.924 44,32.924 24.167,32.924 20.167,32.924 0,32.924 0,28.924 20.167,28.924 z">
        <Path.Style>
            <Style>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <!-- High Alert -->
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AlertState}">
                        <DataTrigger.Value>
                            <enum:AlertState>High</enum:AlertState>
                        </DataTrigger.Value>
                        <Setter Property="Path.Fill" Value="{StaticResource RedFill}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <!-- Medium Alert -->
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AlertState}">
                        <DataTrigger.Value>
                            <enum:AlertState>Medium</enum:AlertState>
                        </DataTrigger.Value>
                        <Setter Property="Path.Fill" Value="{StaticResource OrangeFill}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <!-- Low Alert -->
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding AlertState}">
                        <DataTrigger.Value>
                            <enum:AlertState>Low</enum:AlertState>
                        </DataTrigger.Value>
                        <Setter Property="Path.Fill" Value="{StaticResource YellowFill}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Path.Style>
    </Path>
</Grid>
```

Each UC_Line_x control has almost exactly same code except the difference on the path geometries.
I understand this is a huge code duplications.

I'm considering alternative way to support the same result. Since every pipeline is different only in the path geometries, would it be possible to have a `UC_Line_Path` control based on System.Windows.Form.Path with an extra "AlertState" property to have the following code in the composite UI:

```
<local:UC_Line_Path AlertState="{Binding Pipe1Alert.AlertState}" Data="M20.167,0 L24.167,0 24.167,28.924 44,28.924 44,32.924 24.167,32.924 20.167z"/>
<local:UC_Line_Path AlertState="{Binding Pipe2Alert.AlertState}" Data="M20.167,0 L24.167,0 24.167,28.924 44,28.924 44,32.924 28.924 z"/>
<local:UC_Line_Path AlertState="{Binding Pipe3Alert.AlertState}" Data="M20.167,0 L24.167,0 24.167,28.924 44,28.924 44,32.924 24.167,32.924 20.167,32.924 0,32.924 0,28.924 z"/>
<local:UC_Line_Path AlertState="{Binding Pipe4Alert.AlertState}" Data="M20.167,0 L24.167,0 24.167,28.924  20.167,32.924 0,32.924 0,28.924 20.167,28.924 z"/>
```

The problem of this approach is
1. The Path is a sealed class. The WPF does not allow me to extend it out.
2. Even if assume that I can extend from Path control, How can I add a new property "AlertState" to be used with the data trigger showed in the original UC_Line_1 code?

Thanks and Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a straightforward solution to this.  Use a single control `UC_Line`, and add a property to it `PathData`.  Then you can bind to that property from within the control:

```
<Path x:Name="FL_2" Stretch="Fill" 
    Data="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},Path=PathData}">
```

Then supply the PathData with the instance:

```
<local:UC_Line Margin="27.728,16.486,39.219,36.308" 
               DataContext="{Binding Pipe1Alert}"
               PathData="M20.167,0 L24.167,0 24.167,28.924 44,28.924 44,32.924 24.167,32.924 20.167,32.924 0,32.924 0,28.924 20.167,28.924 z"
/>
```

Note that the property should be a [dependency property](http://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html) of type [`Geometry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public class UC_Line : UserControl
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PathDataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PathData", typeof(Geometry), typeof(UC_Line), null);
    public Geometry PathData
    {
        get { return (Geometry)GetValue(PathDataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PathDataProperty, value); }
    }

    // ... etc
}
```

Comment: Thank you McGarnagle, the solution you put does provided the ability to use PathData for my purpose.